# Who owns Blender?

Tags: development

Blender is an program that has been growing over the past few years through the work of the community. The development of the program is to my understanding largely community based. Although some of the developers get paid by the blender corporate most of the developers work for free while producing an software  with an immense value.

Who owns the rights to the software, to the small contributions made by the users? Are they with the blender corporate?
Is their the legal possibility for Blender corporate to sell the software and therefore realize the immense collectively generated value of Blender?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question as off topic because it is about licensing and legal issues we are neither equipped nor legally authorized to answer, and any ill advice could unintentionally pose a liability to both the user and the network. For official info see the [Blender Licensing Terms and Conditions](https://www.blender.org/about/license/) and the [FAQ about GNU GPL](https://www.blender.org/support/faq/#gnu-gpl)

Answer (score 4):

This is an issue that is covered with the underlying license:

> Blender is released under the [GNU General Public License](http://www.gnu.org/copyleft/gpl.html) (GPL, or “free software”).
>
> This license grants people a number of freedoms:
>
> - You are free to use Blender, for any purpose
> - You are free to distribute Blender
> - You can study how Blender works and change it
> - You can distribute changed versions of Blender
>
> The GPL strictly aims at protecting these freedoms, requiring everyone to share their modifications when they also share the software in public. That aspect is commonly referred to as [Copyleft](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copyleft).
>
> The Blender Foundation and its projects on blender.org are committed to preserving Blender as free software.

[Source](https://www.blender.org/about/license/)

This means that all code is freely available to everyone through the license and thus belongs to everyone (or to nobody).

The Blender Foundation, on the other hand, is only a construct (however financed) whose task is to drive the development forward and explains itself with these words:

> The Blender Foundation (2002) is an independent public benefit organization with the purpose to provide a complete, free and open source 3D creation pipeline, managed by public projects on blender.org.

[Source](https://www.blender.org/about/foundation/)